# Push notifications not sent to device with ad Hoc Profile (using Parse)

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Push is working using my development profile and Im trying to get it working for my Ad Hoc profile.

I inspected the ad hoc profile using a text editor and found:

```
    <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
```

Therefore I have set up a production certificate set up on my app Id:

[image]

1. I re-generated my profile and rebuilt the project with it.
2. I uploaded my Ad Hoc build (to test flight) with the correct certificate (I manually checked it)
3. I checked the device logs and found that it did successfully register the device token:

   `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
           didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken`
    {

   ```
    // Tell Parse about the device token (this gets called)
    [PFPush storeDeviceToken:newDeviceToken];
    ...
   ```

The installation objectes appeared in Parse's web UI.  ([Parse](http://parse.com/) is a backend service for mobile apps)

[image]

The clients pushes appears in the push log (see screenshot 3).  I also created a manual text push from the web UI tool.

[image]

None of the pushes appeared on the device.  I tried with both the app running in the foreground and not running at all (removed from the task bar).

Dose anyone have any suggestions?  Im tired of this... I seam to have tried everything.

Comment: Dumb question, but... have you removed the old profile, installed the new profile in the device and compiled with the new profile ?

Comment: Not a dumb question, and thank you for the response.  I removed the old profile in the organiser and added the new.  I cleaned the build and re-archived it.  I believe if the profile is wrong you get a erro callback in: `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`, wich is not happening for me.

Comment: Have you change your app version to `x.111`? Apple said that you need to make your app version end with 111 for sandbox test.

Comment: What kind of compilation have you done, for your AdHoc version? (run, archive, ...)

Comment: @Martin I built using Archive.

Comment: @fannheyward Very interesting! I will give it a try...  Do you have a reference for it in the Apple Docs?

Comment: Just in case: edit your target scheme, clic on Archive, and make sure the build configuration is "Release".

Answer (score 0):

Seems the you defined the certificate and provisioning profile correctly. Something was missing during the process to sign the Parse connection with APNs or the certificate to send push messages to APNs.

Really sorry for my ridiculous english but this will be a bit long. Did you tried to connect to APNs by hand with your certificate and private keys?

To do that and make things more simple, put your certificate and private key in the same folder, after then open terminal and go to the same folder you put cert and key files and run this command:

```
 openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert YourCertFileHere -key YourPrivateKeyFileHere
```

... and type the passphrase for the key

If everything goes fine, you will connect to APNs via telnet and the connection will be not dropped, otherwise, you don't have a valid pair of files (key and cert).

Other possible reason is Parse trying to send push messages to sandbox server, I can't figure out how can you confirm this because I don't have experience with this BaaS.

I hope this can help you.